# image_downsize returning an Array?

Tags: images

I'm attempting to generate a thumbnail for an image I have posted, but it seems when I call image_downsize, the index[0] actually prints an array as the URL. I'm a bit confused, so any help would be appreciated!

My code:

```
$wpUploadPath = wp_upload_dir();
$target_path = $wpUploadPath;
$filename = 'http://www.mysite.org/uploads/sampleFile.jpeg';

$fileNameFinal = pathinfo($filename);

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null);

$attachment = array(
 'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
 'post_title' => $fileNameFinal['filename'],
 'post_content' => '',
 'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $target_path);

$upFile = image_downsize( $attach_id, 'thumbnail' );
```

Here is where I encounter the problem. If I `print_r($upFile);` I get:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => http://www.mysite.org/uploads/Array
    [1] => 0 
    [2] => 0 
    [3] =>
)
```

Is this normal? I can't seem to generate the thumbnail to update my user meta's with this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Tre

Comment: What is the value of $attach_id?

Comment: the value is 266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_downsize

> **Returns:** 
>   (bool|array) False on failure, array on success. Array with image url, width, height, and whether is intermediate size, in
>   that order is returned on success is returned. $is_intermediate is
>   true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original.

I am going to assume the array within the array part is completely odd.

So let's start working backwards...

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment

> Returns an array of key => value pairs containing path information on
>   the currently configured uploads directory.

Example:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
echo $upload_dir['baseurl'];
```

I see that you have this instead:

```
$wpUploadPath = wp_upload_dir(); // this returns an array!
$target_path = $wpUploadPath; // now the target_path is an array?
```

That is setting the target path to an array instead of a string...

Also - target_path shouldn't be a full path..it should be the file name.
The whole purpose of wp_upload_dir() is to determine the path.

The usage of wp_insert_attachement is as follows:

```
wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id )
```

Notice how it says $filename.

Since you are passing $target_path as the second parameter into wp_insert_attachement() and that second parameter is intended to represent the filename,  it makes the most sense that this is your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was looking at the screen for too long!